# Leitura e escrita de arquivo binário em iteração

Tags: c++, arquivo

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade que requer que criemos um sistema que grave várias estruturas lidas da saída padrão em um arquivo binário, levando à necessidade(?) do uso de iteração.

Ao contrário da facilidade que temos nos arquivos de texto, estou tendo problemas na escrita (função InserirDados, não tenho certeza de que está certo) e na leitura (ListaDados):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct PersonagemDesenho {//declarando a estrutura que vai carregar os dados do personagem
   string nomePersonagem, nomeCriador;
   string tituloDesenho, relacoesPersonagem;
};


void InserirDados () {

    //variavel para criacao do vetor de registro que sera informado pelo usuario
    int quantidade;

    cout << "Quantos personagens voce pretende inserir nesta sessao?" << endl;
    cin >> quantidade;

    //criando espaco na memoria para utilizacao de um vetor dinamico
    PersonagemDesenho* objPersonagem = new PersonagemDesenho[quantidade];

    //declarando o fluxo de dados e criando o arquivo em modo de escrita
    ofstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);

    //conferir se o arquivo foi criado com sucesso
    if (!arquivo) {
        ofstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);
    }

    //limpa o buffer do cin
    cin.ignore ();

    //como usaremos getline, espacos serao permitidos
    cout << "(A utilizacao de espacos e' permitida para todos os itens a seguir)" << endl;

    //descricao das caracteristicas e tudo mais dos personagens
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
        cout << " - PERSONAGEM NUMERO: " << i + 1 << endl;

        cout << "Digite o nome do personagem a ser inserido" << endl;
        //getline para pegar o sobrenome e/ou nomes compostos
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].nomePersonagem);

        cout << "Digite o nome do criador do personagem" << endl;
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].nomeCriador);

        cout << "Digite o titulo do desenho ao qual o personagem pertence" << endl;
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].tituloDesenho);

        cout << "Digite personagens relacionados ao personagem principal" << endl;
        getline(cin, objPersonagem[i].relacoesPersonagem);

        //CODIGO DE GRAVAÇÃO
        arquivo.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&objPersonagem[i]), sizeof(PersonagemDesenho));
        }
    cout << "As informacoes serao salvas no arquivo \"personagens.dat\"" << endl;
    //fechamento do arquivo
    arquivo.close();
    //if conferindo se o arquivo criado corretamente
    if(arquivo){
        cout << "As informacoes foram salvas com sucesso!" << endl;
    }
}

void AtualizaDados () {

}

void BuscaDados () {

}

void ListaDados () {

    ifstream arquivo ("personagens.dat", ios::binary);
    int i = 0;

    while (???) {
        arquivo.read(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&objPersonagens[i]) sizeof(PersonagemDesenho))
        i++;
    }
}

int main () {

    char opcaoEscolhida;

    cout << "Digite o numero referente a opcao que procura" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Digite \"1\" para inserir dados no sistema" << endl;
    cout << "Digite \"2\" para atualizar os dados existentes" << endl;
    cout << "Digite \"3\" para realizar uma busca nos dados salvos" << endl;
    cout << "Digite \"4\" para listar os dados salvos em ordem alfabetica" << endl;
    cout << "Pressione qualquer outra tecla para sair do sistema" << endl;

    cin >> opcaoEscolhida;

    if (opcaoEscolhida == '1') {
        InserirDados ();
    }
        else if (opcaoEscolhida == '2') {
            AtualizaDados ();
        }
            else if (opcaoEscolhida == '3') {
                BuscaDados ();
            }
                else if (opcaoEscolhida == '4') {
                    ListaDados ();
                }
                    else {
                        cout << "Valor invalido" << endl;
                    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como você vai ler da "saída padrão"?

Comment: Dentro do meu for tem um getline (cin, string) para cada campo, como eu não sei montar a estrutura para ler o que tem no arquivo, não sei se está certo.